# Unable to setup private instance of webpagetest tool

Tags: windows, xampp, wampserver, webpagetest

I am trying to setup webpagetest using the link https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/private-instances

**Apache** and **PHP** servers are running successful.

I tried to check installation status using the link http://localhost/webpagetest/install/  This is showing as below

[image]

Seems like **ffmpeg** is the issue. But not sure why rendering is not happening properly. ffmpeg is for video I assume.

**One more question is**: How does my server know the address of the test agents? Do I have to provide IP in the **location**.ini??

**Updates**

Page is rendering. Now how can I find the KEY?

Comment: Create a Virtual Host for this project [see thsi for help doing that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: very good link but did not help me :(

Comment: You may have to reinstall into the VH using the domain name of the VH

Comment: unfortunately I am from .NET background. I appreciate you trying to help but these are new to me.  So what does "reinstall in to Virtual Host" means? Do I have to redeploy code in to VH folder?

Comment: Also, How server will know the test agent address?

Comment: Virtual Hosts are an Apache concept. Its a way of running many sites from one apache instance. The main benefit to you is that each site gets its own specific DocumentRoot, therefore code written to expect to be in the documentroot is in the document root rather than a subfolder of some other DocumentRoot. I think your issue is the the CSS is not getting download from a relative path and therefore you see this page without any css applied

Comment: Either that or place the App in the `htdocs` folder and not a subfolder. But that way you can only ever have one site under development at any one time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126208/discussion-between-codetoshare-and-riggsfolly).